# Getting the specific part of a JSON

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have an API and I use that API to get the exchange rates.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/3307b104e7b3be179b55050e/latest/USD');
$currency = $res->getBody();
```

I want to get the `conversion_rates` data only from the JSON and ignore the rest.

I use Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

might work

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/3307b104e7b3be179b55050e/latest/USD');

$data = $res->getBody()->getContents();
$dataArray = json_decode($data, true);
$rates = $dataArray['conversion_rates'] ?? [];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `$res->json()['conversion_rates']`

Calling it from tinker (just to test):

```php
Http::withOptions(['verify' => false])
    ->get('https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/3307b104e7b3be179b55050e/latest/USD')
    ->json()['conversion_rates'];
```

it gives back

```
=> [
     "USD" => 1,
     "AED" => 3.6725,
     "AFN" => 104.838,
     "ALL" => 106.8525,
     "AMD" => 482.8513,
     ...
   ]
```

Final solution, based on your editing:

```php
$response = Http::withOptions(['verify' => false])
    ->get('https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/3307b104e7b3be179b55050e/latest/USD');

$conversion_rates = $response->json()['conversion_rates'];
```

Comment: I get this error Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response::json()
please check i edited the question.

Comment: Just copy the code I provided, use http instead

Comment: I copied this $res->json()['conversion_rates']

Comment: It gives error ```ErrorException Array to string conversion```  after your edit.

Comment: can you share your code now?

Comment: This is my code ```        $response = Http::withOptions(['verify' => false])
    ->get('https://v6.exchangerate-api.com/v6/3307b104e7b3be179b55050e/latest/USD');

echo $conversion_rates = $response->json()['conversion_rates'];```

Comment: Echo is the error. You can dd, dump, var_dump, whatever, but not echo.

Comment: the result is an array, you can't echo it. Anyway, Vote the answer if solved your problem